# method getItemcount in adapter of recylerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, null, adapter

here code is Of  the class

```
public class AdapterOrderShop extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterOrderShop.HolderOrderShop>
implements Filterable {

private Context context;
public ArrayList<ModelOrderShop> orderShopArrayList,filterList;
private FilterOrderShop filter;

 public AdapterOrderShop(Context context, ArrayList<ModelOrderShop> orderShopArrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.orderShopArrayList = orderShopArrayList;

    this.filterList=orderShopArrayList;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
     return orderShopArrayList.size();
}
```

Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null
object reference

Comment: As the error says, You didn't set the list and it is null. Are You passing a list in the constructor to the Adapter? You have to init `orderShopArrayList` in some way. Maybe show full adapter class and a place where You create it and someone will help You, now I think it is impossible

Answer (score 0):

You should initialize your list in the `adapter` constructor and the problem is solved. Uninitialized list return the null that why this error occur. You can create the constructor in `adapter` and then the list passing from the `activity` or `fragment` assign to the list declare in the `adapter`. If you are passing the `context` from the `activity` or `fragment` then you have the same constructor just like below but if you are not passing the `context` then remove the `Context` parameter from the constructor.

```
public YourAdapterName(Context mCtx, List<YourModelClassName> taskList) {
    this.mCtx = mCtx;
    this.orderShopArrayList= taskList;
}
```

Comment: public AdapterOrderShop(Context context, ArrayList<ModelOrderShop> orderShopArrayList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.orderShopArrayList = orderShopArrayList;
        this.filterList=orderShopArrayList;
    }
We worked the code but the problem remained

Comment: update your question with full adapter code or the list passing from the activity. then it will be clear to trace the problem.

Comment: Iam udate the Question

Comment: add the code from where you passing the list to the adapter

Comment: Activity code from where you passing the list to the recyclerview adapter i wants that one.

Comment: the code is update

Comment: bro you did not getting my point i wants activity code bro

Comment: what is the soultion            https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64803870/push-notification-with-fcm-by-topic-android